# count after difference between two columns with django

Tags: django, math, sum, expression, annotate

I have a table with the following data.

**table_1**

| col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |

I want to add a with b. I can do this with annotate:

```
table_1.objects.annotate(diff=F('col_a ')+F('col_b '))
```

what I can't do is apply a filter.
Example.
count where col_a  + col_b  is greater than 2:

Desired result: 1

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on the `diff`, and then count the number of records:

```
from django.db.models import F

table_1.objects.annotate(
    diff=F('col_a')+F('col_b')
).filter(
    diff__gt=2
).count()
```